# nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:64

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

So I am trying to block certain web browsers (not that you need to know) and everyone says to add if ($http_user_agent ~* (Chrome) ) {
return 403;
}

I do all of that and when I run nginx -t it says this:  nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:64

Do you guys know why?

Comment: `if` can only be placed within a `server` or `location` block. Anywhere else will cause that error.

Comment: Then what should I do? I've been trying everything.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and identify which file contains the `server` block for your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx only allowed `if` to be placed in a `server` or `location` block. `if` should also not be in nginx.conf mostly, while it should be on `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/name.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available/name.conf`.

You also can't put a `server` or `location` block in nginx.conf because it would just give another error.